# asp.net cannot upload more than 25mb or receive 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, upload, web.config

The upload used to work without issue before, and I cannot find anything that might have changed, except I did do updates on all servers.

I rebooted all servers and tried uploading files, and the 404 Error is still present.

Specs and Information on site and issue.

> Windows 2016 Server Core Setup
> IIS 10
> ARR Server Farm (4 ARR Servers) with/
> ------6 Web Servers/
> ------3 SQL Server Cores
> Website = **Session State** [SQL Server] =
> [data source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI] Time-out (280)

**Web.Config** (File located in Root and SubFolder) All IIS Servers would be restarted using the **IISRESET** command during testing.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="555555"/>
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="555555555"/>
```

> **Uploading Media files**
> Bit rate 320kbps
> Files sizes are between 6mb and 30mb each.

If I upload multiple files totaling 23-25mb, everything is OK.
I tested a single file at 28MB and uploaded it without issue.

I receive the following error if I upload multiple files totaling over 25MB.

> **Server Error**
>
> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
> might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
> unavailable.

When I upload files, I can watch the folder and see files coming in and moving to their proper location after database insertion. So it is working like it is supposed to until I upload multiple files with a combined totaling over 25MB.

Any information on this would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
For those who are running a setup as I am.

> 4 ARR Core Servers
> ^--->Shared Configuration Files
>
> 6 Web Core Server
> ^--->Shared Configuration Files

When setting up IIS on the Main IIS Server, ensure your Web and ARR Servers have identical Request Filtering Settings.
If the ARR Server differs from the Web Servers, you will experience this issue.

In **IIS**
Click on the Server Name [**ServerName (DomainName\ServerUser)**]
In the Center, under IIS, Double-click on [**Request Filtering**]
On the Right Panel, click on [**Edit Feature Settings**]

Under = [**Request Limits**]

> Maximum allowed content length (Bytes)
> (Original ARR Server 2016 Desktop Experience)
> ^--> 1000000000 (Equals 1000 MB)
> (New Configuration Web Servers)
> ^--> 555555555 (Equals 555.5 MB)
> (New ARR Server Core)
> ^--> 30000000 (Equals 30 MB)

After changing the Main New ARR Server Core IIS to match that of the Web Servers,
And the Shared Config copied everything over. Finally, the upload script began working as intended.

Always ensure all settings in IIS match in ARR and the Web Servers.